# Avoid code duplication in Rspec + Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Let's say I have test on new input and test on new input when input is invalid (first test is on case input is valid).

For example (from my code):

```
 scenario "valid input saving" do
    visit program_stream_path(@program, @stream)
    click_link "#link"
    fill_in "#fill_in", :with=>"1"
    click_button "Next"
    expect(page).to have_current_path new_students_list_stream_path(@stream)
    within("#student_0") do
    fill_in "Имя", :with => "Name"
    fill_in "Фамилия", :with => "Surname"
    fill_in "Электронная почта", :with => "randommail@mail.com"
    end
    print page.html
    click_button "Save"
    expect(page).to have_current_path program_stream_path(@program, @stream)
#...other code
end
```

Obviously, test that checks behavior on invalid input repeats this part:

```
  scenario "invalid input leads to correct input page" do
  visit program_stream_path(@program, @stream)
        click_link "#link"
        fill_in "#fill_in", :with=>"1"
        click_button "Next"
        expect(page).to have_current_path new_students_list_stream_path(@stream)
          #other code
```

How to avoid this copy-paste way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use before blocks for this kind of thing

```
feature "..." do
  before :each do
    visit program_stream_path(@program, @stream)
    click_link "#link"
    fill_in "#fill_in", :with=>"1"
    click_button "Next"
    expect(page).to have_current_path new_students_list_stream_path(@stream)
  end

  scenario "valid input saving"
     #unique code for this scenario
  end

  scenario "invalid input leads to correct input page"
    # unique code for this scenario
  end
end
```

The outer feature block could be a describe or a scenario block if wanted/needed since you can nest multiple levels.  If you need to use the code across multiple feature files then it makes sense to move it to a method in one of your spec helper files.

Answer (score 0):

You can place it in a method in your spec file like this and reuse it.

```
scenario "valid input saving" do
  your_named_method
  ...
end

scenario "invalid input leads to correct input page" do 
  your_named_method
  ...
end

def your_named_method
  visit program_stream_path(@program, @stream)
  click_link "#link"
  fill_in "#fill_in", :with=>"1"
  click_button "Next"
  expect(page).to have_current_path new_students_list_stream_path(@stream)
end
```

Comment: Ah I didn't know that

Comment: I edited my answer. I was unaware scenario was an alias for ```it```. I always use ```it```

Answer (score 0):

A great way to avoid duplication when testing with Capybara is to use [**Capybara Test Helpers**](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/).

```rb
RSpec.feature 'Program Stream', test_helpers: [:programs] do
  before { visit program_stream_path(@program, @stream) }

  scenario 'valid input saving' do
    programs.click_to_add_student
    programs.should.be_adding_a_student(@stream)
    programs.add_student(name: 'Имя', surname: 'Фамилия', email: 'randommail@mail.com')
    programs.should.have_new_student('Имя')
  end

  scenario 'invalid input leads to correct input page' do
    programs.click_to_add_student
    programs.should.be_adding_a_student(@stream)
    programs.add_student(name: nil, surname: nil, email: nil)
    programs.should.have_invalid_form("Name can't be blank")
  end
end
```

Besides reducing code duplication, it has the benefit of being a lot [more descriptive](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/guide/essentials/actions.html#finding-the-right-balance-%E2%9A%96%EF%B8%8F), which can help to make tests a lot easier to maintain in the long term.

```rb
class ProgramsTestHelper < Capybara::TestHelper
# Actions: Encapsulate complex actions to provide a cleaner interface.
  def click_to_add_student
    click_link '#link'
    fill_in '#fill_in', with: '1')
    click_button "Next"
  end

  def add_student(name:, surname:, email:)
    fill_in 'Имя', with: name
    fill_in 'Фамилия', with: surname
    fill_in 'Электронная почта', with: email
    click_button 'Save'
  end

# Assertions: Allow to check on element properties while keeping it DRY.
  def be_adding_a_student(stream)
    have_current_path urls.new_students_list_stream_path(stream)
  end

  def have_new_student(name)
    have_content(name)
  end

  def have_invalid_form(message)
    have('form', text: message)
  end
end
```

Have in mind that you could choose to combine `click_to_add_student` with `add_student`, running assertions inside the helper methods. It all boils down to [how much granularity you need in tests](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/guide/essentials/actions.html#finding-the-right-balance-%E2%9A%96%EF%B8%8F).

[Passing blocks to methods](https://github.com/ElMassimo/capybara_test_helpers/blob/master/examples/rails_app/spec/system/cities_spec.rb#L18-L20) is also a nice way to customize interactions or outcomes.